# drawable assets will not link android

Tags: android, xml

I have been working on a project, adding drawable assets in the project without a problem. That is, until recently. I just tried running my project again and now none of my assets in my drawable folder will link successfully. I haven't done anything different than I had been doing and I really do not know what could have caused this issue. I have looked everywhere and I find resolutions for individual assets not linking but nothing about how to resolve a whole directory of assets not linking. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try invalidating the cache and restarting or clean build ?

Comment: @thebadassdev this solved my issue, thank you!

Comment: Great! you can upvote the answer so that others will find it useful! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check the xml layouts and resources
aapt would not add new drawable if there is an error in layouts in some IDE